# Outline/Border rendering issue in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, less

I noticed a strange behaviour when animating a border/outline color change in chrome. The right border/outline of my element does not correctly animate from white to red and stays red after mouse leaves the element. Scrolling the page forces the border/outline to display correctly.

**Standard state:**

[image: Standard state]

**Broken hover state:**

[image: Broken hover state]

**After mouse leaves:**

[image: After mouse leaves]

**Thin grey border right (after mouse leave, sometimes):**

[image]

**Desired result (working on IE, Firefox, Opera):**

[image]

**My CSS (LESS) for the element:**

```
a {
    display: inline-block;

    padding: 1em 3em;

    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: white;
    color: @hue-red;
    background: white;

    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: center;

    transition: color 200ms, outline 200ms;

    .gfx(arrow-circled-right);

    &:before {
        font-size: 1.8em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }

    &:hover, &:focus {
        color: darken(@hue-red, 5%);
        outline-color: darken(@hue-red, 5%);
    }
}
```

I tried to switch from border to outline and back with the exact same result.

Edit: I cannot reproduce the error any more, so I'm closing the question.

Comment: Well, now I can't even reproduce the error where it initially occurred. Thanks Obama.

Comment: @phippu: Voting to close based on your update mate. If you come across the same issue again, please add a fiddle (or some demo) to the question.

Comment: It seems to depend on other elements on the page, I suspect ```transform: translate(x, y)``` on some parent element. I'll edit the post with a URL to the project, maybe someone can reproduce the issue.